# Converting seconds to minutes and formatting axes

Tags: d3.js

I have data in the format of seconds. I would like to convert the seconds data to hours and minutes and display this data along an axis. For example, I've been trying to do this like this:

```
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(x)
        .orient("bottom")
        .tickFormat(function(d) {return d/60});
```

I see that D3 has a time formatter, but I can't seem to get it to display the proper format. What I'm looking for is a a way in D3 to convert data in seconds to hours and minutes. How can I do this?

Comment: The time functions are the way to go. What have you tried and what didn't work?

Comment: Thanks for the help. I've tried using time functions like this: `format = d3.time.format("%M");` Calling `format(200)` doesn't format the time properly though.

Comment: Ah, I think I misunderstood what you're trying to do. Your times are relative to a start and not absolute (i.e. Unix timestamp)? Then what you're doing is the best way to handle this -- the time functions are meant for working with absolute times.

Comment: Yes, my times are relative. I was hoping D3 had a built in way to handle this.

Comment: Not unless you convert them to absolute times.

Comment: Do you have a start time which the subsequent times are offset from?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11286872/how-do-i-make-a-custom-axis-formatter-for-hours-minutes-in-d3-js

Answer (score 3):

Here's the answer for posterity (when you set the date, it should be relative to when you're initializing your other Date objects, if necessary):

```
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(x)
        .orient("bottom")
        .tickFormat(function(d) {
            return d3.timeFormat('%-M')( new Date(0).setSeconds(d) ) # formats minutes
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(x)
        .orient("bottom")
        .tickFormat(function(d) {
        var minutes = Math.floor(d / 60000);
        var seconds = +((d % 60000) / 1000).toFixed(0);
        return (seconds == 60 ? (minutes+1) + ":00" : minutes + ":" + (seconds < 10 ? "0" : "") + seconds);

});
```

This will convert milliseconds to minutes and seconds.