# Major ticks in d3.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I plotted a d3 graph in which in have many dates and those dates gets increased day by day so my x axis looks grabled with so many daes so I want to set major ticks in my graph n xaxis. I tried but not able to get it.So please suggest.
Here is my code:

```
<div id="chart"></div>
    </div>
    <script>
    var jsonURL = 'avb.json';

    var myData = [];
    var fliterdata = [];
    var tempdata = [];
    var selectop = "";
    var selectDate = false;
    var chartType = chartType || 'bar';

    function filterJSON(json, key, value) {
        var result = [];
        for (var foo in json) {
         var extractstr = json[foo][key] ;
          extractstr=String(extractstr);

            if (extractstr.slice(3)== value) {

                result.push(json[foo]);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    function selectValue(d) {
        switch (selectop) { //d object select particular value for Y axis 
            case "01":
                return d.val001;
                break;
            case "02":
                return d.val002;
                break;
            default:
                //console.log("default");
                return d.val001;
        }
    }

    var margin = {
        top: 20,
        right: 0,
        bottom: 80,
        left: 40
    };
    var width = 700 - margin.left - margin.right;
    var height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;



    var xScale = d3.scale.ordinal().rangeRoundBands([0, width], .1);
    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
     .scale(xScale)
      .tickValues(xScale.domain().filter(function(d, i) { return !(i % 2);                       }))
   .orient("bottom");

    var yScale = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);
    var hAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(xScale).orient('bottom').tickFormat(d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d"));
    var vAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(yScale).orient('left');
    var tooltip = d3.select('body').append('div')
        .style('position', 'absolute')
        .style('background', '#f4f4f4')
        .style('padding', '5 15px')
        .style('border', '1px #333 solid')
        .style('border-radius', '5px')
        .style('opacity', 'o');

    var line = d3.svg.line()
        .x(function(d) {
            return xScale(d.date);
        })
        .y(function(d) {
            return yScale(selectValue(d));
        })
        .interpolate("monotone")
        .tension(0.9);


    function render(filterByDates) {


        d3.select('svg').remove();

        if (filterByDates) {
            selectDate = true;
            tempData = fliterdata;
            console.log("before date fliter data", tempData);
            var date1 = new Date(document.getElementById('field1').value);
            var date2 = new Date(document.getElementById('field2').value);

            tempData = tempData.filter(function(d) {
                console.log(date1, date2);
                //  alert(date1);
                return d.date >= date1 && d.date <= date2;
            });
        }


        xScale.domain(tempData.map(function(d) {
            return d.date;
        }).sort(function(a, b) {
            return a > b;
        }));

        yScale.domain([0, d3.max(tempData, function(d) {
            return +selectValue(d);
        })]);

        var svg = d3.select('#chart').append('svg')
            .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
            .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
            .append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

        svg

            .append('g')
            .attr("class", "x axis")
            .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
            .call(hAxis)
            .selectAll("text")
            .style("text-anchor", "end")
            .attr("dx", "-.8em")
            .attr("dy", "-.55em")
            .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)");

        svg
            .append('g')
            .attr("class", "yaxis")
            .call(vAxis)

        if (chartType == 'bar') {
            svg
                .selectAll(".bar") //makes bar
                .data(tempData)
                .enter().append("rect")
                .attr("class", "bar")
                .style("fill", "red")
                .attr("x", function(d) {
                    return xScale(d.date);
                }).attr("width", xScale.rangeBand())
                .attr("y", function(d) {


                    return yScale(selectValue(d));
                }).attr("height", function(d) {

                    console.log("as", d.value);
                    return height - yScale(selectValue(d));
                }).on('mouseover', function(d) {
                    tooltip.transition()
                        .style('opacity', 1)

                    tooltip.html(d.value)
                        .style('left', (d3.event.pageX) + 'px')
                        .style('top', (d3.event.pagey) + 'px')
                    d3.select(this).style('opacity', 0.5)
                }).on('mouseout', function(d) {
                    tooltip.transition()
                        .style('opacity', 0)
                    d3.select(this).style('opacity', 1)
                });
        }

        if (chartType == 'line') {
            svg.append("path") // Add the line path.
                .data(tempData)
                .attr("class", "line")
                .attr("d", line(tempData));
        }

    }

    d3.json(jsonURL, function(data) {

        myData = data; //data from json in mydata
        myData.forEach(function(d) {

            d.date = new Date(d.date);
        });

        $("#listbox").on("click", function() {

            var key = $(this).val();
            console.log("key:", key);
            var value = $('#listbox option:selected').text();
            //value = "int" + value;
            console.log("vaue:", value);

            selectop = String(key);

            selectop = selectop.slice(-2);
            console.log("mydata: ", myData);
            console.log("selectops:", selectop);

            fliterdata = filterJSON(myData, key, value); //selected value from user and picks the whole element that contains that attribute
            tempData = fliterdata; //graph made by temp data
            if (selectDate)
                render(true);
        });
    });

    function selectChartType(type) {
        chartType = type;
        render(true);
    }
    </script>
</body>
</html>

{
"name": "ABC",
 "date": 1461176704000,
 "attr001": "intSIGN1",
 "val001": "200", 
"attr002": "intSIGN2", 
"val002": "70", 
"attr003": "dt1SIGN3", 
"val003": "57.5",
 "attr004": "intSIGN4",
 "val004": "670",
 "attr005": "strSIGN5", 
"val005": "Traceinvalid"
 }, 

{ "name": "ABC",
 "date": 1459125900000,
 "attr001": "intSIGN1",
 "val001": "500", 
"attr002": "intSIGN2", 
"val002": "70", 
"attr003": "intSIGN3", 
"val003": "100.00",
 "attr004": "intSIGN4",
 "val004": "670",
 "attr005": "strSIGN5", 
"val005": "Traceinvalid"
 },




 { "name": "XYZ", 
"date": 145877400000, 
"attr001": "intVISSE1",
 "val001": "100", 
"attr002": "intVISSE2",
 "val002": "7",
 "attr003": "dt1VISSE3",
 "val003": "39.67",
 "attr004": "intVISSE4",
 "val004": "160",
 "attr005": "strSIGN5", 
"val005": "not found"
 },

 { "name": "XYZ",
 "date": 1461535200000,
 "attr001": "intVISSE1", 
"val001": "50", 
"attr002": "intVISSE2",
 "val002": "70",
 "attr003": "dt1VISSE3",
 "val003": "300.00",
 "attr004": "intVISSE4",
 "val004": "230",
  "attr005": "strSIGN5", 
"val005": "found"
 },

{ "name": "XYZ", 
"date": 1461384717000, 
"attr001": "intVISSE1",
"val001": "300", 
"attr002": "intVISSE2",
 "val002": "10", 
"attr003": "dt1VISSE3", 
"val003": "500.00",
 "attr004": "intVISSE4",
 "val004": "350",
 "attr005": "strSIGN5", 
"val005": "not found" },

{ "name": "ABC", 
"date": 1459051873000, 
"attr001": "intSIGN1",
"val001": "300", 
"attr002": "intVISSE2",
 "val002": "10", 
"attr003": "dt1VISSE3", 
"val003": "500.00",
 "attr004": "intVISSE4",
 "val004": "350",
 "attr005": "strSIGN5", 
"val005": "not found" } ]
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand

`var xScale = d3.scale.ordinal().rangeRoundBands([0, width], .1);`

will give you a scale for each unique value within your domain (in this case your dates), which is why d3 wont be able to reduce tick count in your chart. Try using

```
var xScale = d3.time.scale()
```

which will help you gain more control in the ticks and the format you are trying to achieve.

You can find more info in how the d3 time scale works [here](http://bl.ocks.org/jebeck/9671241) and you can find a question with a really [nice explained answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24541296/d3-js-time-scale-nicely-spaced-ticks-at-minute-intervals-when-data-is-in-second) on why certain scales are better suited for your data.

UPDATE:

If you want fewer ticks using an ordinal scale a nice option would be using

```
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
.scale(xScale)
.tickValues(xScale.domain().filter(function(d, i) { return !(i % 2); }))
.orient("bottom");
```

where the filter function will help decide the tick values of your axis.

Comment: there is no affect after using this var xScale = d3.time.scale()   same scale and values I am still getting !!

Comment: and I donot want any kind of format ..just I want few dates to come on my x axis

Comment: I used this and it gives me error of X is undefined

Comment: Can you try it now? X was the variable holding your scale value, in the updated answer you will find the correct code for your code

Comment: @torresoamar I have checked now but I get error of domain undefined

Comment: @deepsodhi i updated the answer, check if that works

Comment: @torresoamar as u can see I updated my code as suggested by you but I am getting same output as before no change and no error coming in console as well

Comment: @deepsodhi can you provide the json used in your example?

Comment: @torresoamar i have added my json ...have a look