# How to solve TypeError: d3.time is undefined?

Tags: javascript, node.js, d3.js

I want to parse data/time using D3.js. For that purpose I created one javascript file and use `var d3 = require('d3')`.
I install D3 using `npm install d3`, and also tried `npm install d3 --save` which saves it in `package.json` file :

```
{
  "name": "school",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "browserify": "^13.1.0",
    "bufferutil": "^1.2.1",
    "d3": "^4.2.2",
    "express": "^4.14.0",
    "guid": "0.0.12",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "react": "^15.3.1",
    "react-dom": "^15.3.1",
    "reactify": "^1.1.1",
    "utf-8-validate": "^1.2.1",
    "vinyl-source-stream": "^1.1.0",
    "websocket": "^1.0.23",
    "ws": "^1.1.1"
  }
}
```

However, I'm facing this exception:

```
TypeError: d3.time is undefined
```

program code:

```
'use strict';

var d3 = require("d3");
var latency_arr = [];
var time_arr = [];
var timeFormat = d3.time.format('%H:%M:%S %L');

module.exports = {
  histogram: function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    return {

      getBin: function() {

        var jsonObject = JSON.parse(data);
        this.time_arr = jsonObject.time;
        for(var i = 0 ; i < this.time_arr.length ; i++){
            temp_time = this.time_arr[i];
            this.time_arr[i] = new Date(timeFormat.parse(temp_time));
        }
        return this.time_arr;
      },

      addValue: function(date, value) {
        return true;
      },

      getValues: function() {
        if(data !== undefined){
            var jsonObject = JSON.parse(data);
            this.latency_arr = jsonObject.latency;
            return this.latency_arr;
        }
      }
    };
  }
};
```

**Checking :**

```
> var d3 = require('d3');
undefined
```

But the d3 module is in node_modules directory.

Why didn't it recognize the d3 module? What am I missing?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You are requiring D3 **v4.2.2** that doesn't have a `d3.time` property any more, which was part of D3 v3. According to the changelog the [time formats](https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/CHANGES.md#time-formats-d3-time-format) have been subject to the general namespace flattening and were therefore renamed as follows:

> - d3.time.format ↦ [d3.timeFormat](https://github.com/d3/d3-time-format#timeFormat)
> - d3.time.format.utc ↦ [d3.utcFormat](https://github.com/d3/d3-time-format#utcFormat)
> - d3.time.format.iso ↦ [d3.isoFormat](https://github.com/d3/d3-time-format#isoFormat)

That said, it does recognize the `d3` object, wheras the `d3.time` is undefined. Changing your code to

```
var timeFormat = d3.timeFormat('%H:%M:%S %L');
```

should do the trick.

Comment: @altocumulus- ok got it. How I can use **d3.time.scale()** and **d3.scale.linear()** ?

Comment: It's all in the changelog link in the answer. d3.time.scale -> d3.scaleTime and d3.scale.linear -> d3.scaleLinear

Answer (score 0):

The d3 module is recognized. Every assignment in JS returns nothing, therefore executing the line

```
var d3 = require('d3');
```

is bound to return...nothing, hence the `undefined` in your checking (For making sure, just type `var a = 0` in your console, you will also get an `undefined` response). It looks like the function is not defined in the module, rather then the module not being loaded.

You should check the API of the module, to make sure you are using the right function.

L.E. saving you some trouble, here's the link

https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/API.md#time-formats-d3-time-format